# How can I set a timeout on spring DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc

We are using `DriverManagerDataSource` from the Spring framework (version 2.5) to pool connections to Oracle. However, it seems that these connections don't have any timeout defined - yesterday, after emergency database restart, we had a thread hanging on a socket read inside the database connection. How can I set the timeout, to say 10 mins, so that it raises an exception next time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up changing the bean in the Spring context in the following way:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" autowire="no">
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT">60000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I don't know if it works yet.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a builtin connection pool: `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`. I recommend you use that directly. The reference for Oracle JDBC (10gR2, other versions will be similar) is in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/toc.htm. Points of interest:

- [Configuration of data sources](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/urls.htm#BEIDBFDF)
- [Statement caching](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/stmtcach.htm#g1079466)
- [Implicit connection caching](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/concache.htm#CDEGABII) (and specially [timeout properties](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/concache.htm#CACHHIJF))

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle driver implementation supports a timeout property you can pass it through to the underlying implementation via `getConnectionProperties().put(key, timeout)`

I'm assuming you realise that [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) isn't a connection pool?  From the docs:

> **NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually
>   pool Connections.** It just serves as
>   simple replacement for a full-blown
>   connection pool, implementing the same
>   standard interface, but creating new
>   Connections on every call. [..] If you
>   need a "real" connection pool outside
>   of a J2EE container, consider
>   [Apache's Jakarta Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)  or
>   [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).

You may also be interested in [OCI Connection Pooling](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/ociconpl.htm)?