# Setting up connection time out using configuration

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I realized that I haven't set the time out for the [`JDBCTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) using the `setQueryTimeOut` method. My code is in production as I would ideally want a solution to set the timeout from some configuration instead of recompiling the code. Is there a way to set the query time out via say the data source configuration or any other property outside the Java.

I tried via the accepted solution to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700795/how-can-i-set-a-timeout-on-spring-drivermanagerdatasource). Didn't work for me. I get `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'connectionProperties' of bean class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `queryTimeout` field with configuration:

1. In your JDBCTempalte xml - `<property name="queryTimeout" value="${query.timeout}` />
2. Use a [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to load properties from a `.properties` file on the classpath. The easiest way is through `<context:property-placeholder location=".." />`
3. Add the `query.timeout=x` in your `.properties` files